# Using promise on button click in stenciljs

Tags: javascript, promise, stenciljs

I am currently working on a stenciljs App and would like to get some info via a REST service. This REST call is implemented as a function which returns a Promise. Now, if I use this rest call in componentwillload Lifecycle Method, it works fine:

```
async componentWillLoad() {

return getUserData().then( userData => {
  console.log("got userdata", userData);
});
```

}

Now, I would like to get this info when the user clicks a button. For that, I call this method in the click handler for this button:

```
<button id="mybutton" onClick={()=>this._handleButtonClick()></button>

_handleButtonClick() {
  return getUserData().then( userData => {
  console.log("got userdata", userData);
 });
}
```

But this does not work, I see in the Browser console Network Tab that a network call is made but it returns no data. How can I make this thing work

Comment: Why is there an underscore in `_this.handleButtonClick`? And does the request actually return data (i.e. does it have a response in the network tab)? Does "got userdata" get logged out? Are there any errors logged?

Comment: I have corrected the underscore error. Yes, the method does return data, if used, as shown above in the componentWillLoad()  method.

Comment: Can you share the code of `getUserData`? If it doesn't return data, what *does* it return? Or does the callback simply never run? Does the button do anything else?

Comment: Does the **request** have a response **in the network tab**? Do you see "got userdata" in the console log? Are there any errors in the console log? If no, try to reproduce the issue on [webcomponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev) (or a similar site).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing closing brace (})?

`onClick={()=>this._handleButtonClick()` <- here

but assuming that is just a typo, maybe you can just store the result of getUserData in state object (that way, it will trigger `render()` function as your data change)?

Here is how I'm doing the fetch (just as an example)

```
fetch(`REST endpoint`, {
  method: 'GET'
  headers: { // Content-Type and security token }
}).then ((response: Response) => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.dataList = data;
  });
```

(so here, I'm storing result as "dataList", which is defined with @State() dataList)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your button doesn't have an attribute `type="button"`.

You could be running into an edge case scenario where if a button is the first button within a form, and isn't marked as `type="button"`, the browser defaults it to `<button type="submit">`. At that point, clicking on the button might trigger the API call because of the registered listener, but it'll also trigger a form submit.

Since API calls take some time to complete, by the time the response is returned your page may have reloaded because of a form submit.

Again, this is an edge case scenario but looks like a reasonable explanation for what you're observing.